# C variable transfer return error

Tags: c

I have a code which is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int lel(char var[]){
    int i=0,j=0;
    printf("\n\n\n");
    while (var[i]!='\0'){
        printf("%c\n",var[i]);
        if (var[i]!='s'){
            var[j]=var[i];
            j++;
        }
        i++;
    }
    while (j<lenght(var)){
        var[j]='\0';
    }

    return var;
}

int main(){
    char a[10]="123asss1",s[10]="assssssa",d[10]="asdfghj";
    strcpy(a,lel(a));
    strcpy(s,lel(s));
    strcpy(d,lel(d));
    printf("%s\n%s\n%s\n",a,s,d);
}
```

When it is like this it highlights the "return var;" as error. But when i just remove the

```
while (j<lenght(var)){
    var[j]='\0';
}
```

.
It works perfectly fine.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int lel(char var[]){
    int i=0,j=0;
    printf("\n\n\n");
    while (var[i]!='\0'){
        printf("%c\n",var[i]);
        if (var[i]!='s'){
            var[j]=var[i];
            j++;
        }
        i++;
    }
    return var;
}

int main(){
    char a[10]="123asss1",s[10]="assssssa",d[10]="asdfghj";
    strcpy(a,lel(a));
    strcpy(s,lel(s));
    strcpy(d,lel(d));
    printf("%s\n%s\n%s\n",a,s,d);
}
```

I don't get it. Why it's not working just because of a small while loop. And again it highlights the "return var;".

I use Dev C++.

Thanks.

Comment: Well i mean perfectly i didn't mean perfectly. I mean with no errors.

Comment: Btw before you say.

    int lel()........


-Why  you don't make it const char.


-Because it causes another error :D

Comment: `var` is `char *`, but the function is declared to return `int`.

Comment: Should `lenght` instead be `length` in the while loop?

Comment: `strcpy(a,lel(a));` is copying a string to itself, since `lel()` returns a pointer to its input string. `strcpy()` is undefined behavior if the source and destination overlap.

Comment: There's no `length()` function in C. The name of the function is `strlen()`.

Comment: Ty Barmar. Solved

Comment: Btw i still didnt get why return made an error.

Comment: Undefined behavior doesn't always cause an error. Sometimes it seems to work, but there's no guarantee.

Comment: I told you -- You're returning a `char*` when the function is declared `int lel()`

Comment: and when i make int ---> const char it crashes again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several problems.

The warning about `return` is because you have the function declared with an incorrect return type. It should be:

```
char *lel(char var[]) {
    ...
}
```

The `while` loop is wrong because you're calling a nonexistent `length()` function. The function to get the length of a string is `strlen()`. But that loop is unnecessary. `strlen()` works by searching for the first null byte in the string, so after you do `var[j] = '\0';`, the next `strlen()` will return the position of the byte you just added. So just write:

```
var[j] = '\0';
```

without the loop.

There's no need to call `strcpy()` in `main()`. `lel()` modifies the string in place, and returns a pointer to that same string. Copying the string back to itself has no effect, and violates the constraint that the arguments to `strcpy()` must not overlap.